# Python indentation in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, indentation

Boring of googling this question - how to set indentation offset for python in emacs?
Tried many variants, but none helps.
http://jomp.ru/@s.png - python mode?

Comment: You're probably getting downvoted because you say you've tried many methods, but haven't shown us what you've tried with a description of why it isn't working. Edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your .emacs put:

```
(setq python-indent 12)
```

where 12 is the number of the indentation you want.

BTW: you can also use the fancy 'Customize Emacs' menu - it's the first option under  Programming -> Languages -> Python.

Comment: Thanks for answers, that's my fail.

Comment: As of Emacs 24.3 it's python-indent-offset.